# Converting textbox.text to textbox.backcolor

Tags: vb.net

Okay so I'm trying to convert the `backColor` of a `textbox` to the text that's in the textbox (this is in VB)

This is what I have but it says I can't convert string to color:

```
textbox.backColor = textbox.text   (example of text in the box "ff000000")
```

The way I got the text was by converting a textbox's backcolor to text with this:

```
TextBox3.Text = TextBox2.BackColor.Name
```

Comment: You didn't convert the textbox's backcolor to text.  You just assigned a the name of the color (a string)  to textbox3.text (another string).

Comment: yes I realised that, I wanted the name of the color? but I want to use the name of that color on another textboxs backcolor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **ColorTranslator** class to do this. I am assuming it's RGB... This takes a hex code and converts it to its color...

```
 Dim col As System.Drawing.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(txtbox.Text.Trim())

 If col IsNot Nothing Then
    txtbox.BackColor = col
 End If
```

Comment: just had to make one tweek 
Dim col As System.Drawing.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#" & txtbox.Text.Trim())